# neo4j group by and sum values

Tags: neo4j, sum, cypher, grouping

I have a cypher query that produces the following result:

```
A  1
A  2
A  3
B  1
B  2
```

And I would like to group the same values of the first property and sum them up so the result would be:

```
A  6
B  3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n.name, n.number
```

Simply add the `SUM` aggregation function and they will be automatically grouped.

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n.name, sum(n.number)
```